# How to add an option into a custom created dropdown-attribute for category in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, category, dropdown-attribute

I have created a custom dropdown-attribute for magento category with few option, Now I want to add one more option to this select attribute. Is there any way to do this without deleting the existing attribute.

```
    $setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');
    $setup->startSetup();

    $setup->addAttribute('catalog_category', 'price_base_unit', array(
        'group'         => 'Order Units',
        'input'         => 'select',
        'type'          => 'varchar',
        'option' => array ('value' => array(
                         'optionone'=> array(
                        0 =>'Bag'),
                            'optiontwo'=> array(
                        0 =>'Kg'),
                            'optionthree'=> array(
                        0 =>'Piece'),
                            'optionfour'=> array(
                        0 =>'Sq. ft'),
                            'optionfive'=> array(
                        0 =>'Cu. ft'),
                            'optionsix'=> array(
                        0 =>'litre'))),
        'label'         => 'Price base unit',
        'backend'       => '',
        'visible'       => 1,
        'required'      => 0,
        'user_defined' => 1,
        'global'        => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
    ));

    $setup->endSetup();
```

Comment: Can you share,custom dropdown-attribute  installer code?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the following code snippet

```
    $attrModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/resource_eav_attribute')->loadByCode('catalog_category', 'price_base_unit');

    $option['attribute_id'] = $attrModel->getAttributeId();
    $option['value']['new_option'][0] = 'new_option_value';

    $setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');
    $setup->addAttributeOption($option);
```